# Show boostrap modal immediately without waiting for content to load

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, modal-dialog

I'm using a bootstap modal popup in my application. Here is the problem I'm running into and have not been able to find a solution for.

Let's say I have a click event listener that looks like this:

```
jQuery("#show-invoice").click(function(){
       jQuery('#invoice-details').modal('show');

       ...a call to an api to retrieve invoice details...
       ...it takes about 2-3 seconds to retrieve...
});
```

The issue is when I click the *#show-invoice* link in Chrome, the modal waits for the api call to complete and thus creates a 2-3 second delay before the modal window is shown. In Firefox, the modal window shows right away, which makes sense, because *jQuery('#invoice-details').modal('show');* is run before anything else.

So my question is, how do I make the modal window show as soon as the even occurs and not wait for the anything after *jQuery('#invoice-details').modal('show');* in all browsers?

Comment: Ideally, it should have shown immediately. I dont find a reason why it would wait for the API call to complete. Can you please paste your whole code to check whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show modal immediately

```
jQuery('#invoice-details').modal('show');
```

After this you can do async ajax call. 
While the data is loading, you should display load icon instead invoice details in your modal. After data will load you can replace icon with new loaded data. Something like this:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'invoice_details_url',
    type: 'get',
    success: function ( invoice_details_data ) {
       jQuery('#invoice-details .invoice-details-container').
              empty().append(invoice_details_data);
    },
    async:true,
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm certainly aware of the async call to fix it. My only hesitation is my code works fine in FF, so to me it appears as if some obscure parameter is missing to make it work in Chrome. If I cannot find a solution, then yes, I will certainly recode the function to use an async call.